# d3js - how to prevent the `line` from `null` values in json data?

Tags: json, d3.js

I am getting the `json` data from back-end to draw the `line`. the problem what i am getting is, even if the data is being as `null` ( out of 20 say 5 doesn't have data ) i am getting `line` drawn in.

what i expect is, I don't want to draw the lines once the data has the values as null.

example data :

```
[

  {
    "ActualPercentage": 48.78,
    "PlanPercentage": 44.05,
    "Week": "2015-10-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 45.25,
    "Week": "2015-11-29T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 46.45,
    "Week": "2015-12-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 47.65,
    "Week": "2016-01-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 48.85,
    "Week": "2016-02-28T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 50.05,
    "Week": "2016-03-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 51.25,
    "Week": "2016-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 100,
    "Week": "2016-05-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 100,
    "Week": "2016-06-29T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 100,
    "Week": "2016-07-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": 100, //let this line alone stop here.
    "Week": "2016-08-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null, //still drawing!?
    "Week": "2016-09-29T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2016-10-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2016-11-29T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2016-12-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2017-01-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2017-02-27T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2017-03-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2017-04-29T18:30:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "ActualPercentage": 100,
    "PlanPercentage": null,
    "Week": "2017-05-30T18:30:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

I am drawing 2 lines here. let first line draw as fill data and second one let stop up to it's find the value.

how to do this?

here is my code :

```
var that  = this;

            var parseDate = d3.time.format("%Y%m%d").parse;

            var width = this.width;
            var height = this.height;

            var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
            var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

            var toolTipScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([height + 90, 80]).range([0, 100]);
            var iScale = d3.scale.linear().domain([width + 80, 80]).range([this.datas.length, 0]);

            var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
                      .domain(["ActualPercentage", "PlanPercentage", "WeeklyActual", "WeeklyPlan"])
                      .range(["#FF0000", "#009933" , "#FFFFFF", "#ff0099"]);

            var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
                .scale(x)
                .tickSize(-height)
                .ticks(d3.time.month, 1)
                .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%Y-%b"))
                .tickSubdivide(true)
                .orient("bottom")
                .outerTickSize(0); //removing right border as the way top too.

            var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).tickSize( -width ).tickSubdivide(true).orient("left").outerTickSize(0);

            var line = d3.svg.line()
                // .interpolate("basis")
                .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
                .defined(function(d) { return d.y; })
                .y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); }); 

            var svg = this.svg;

            var div = d3.select("body").append("div")
                     .attr("class", "tooltips")
                     .style("opacity", 0);


              color.domain(d3.keys(this.datas[0]).filter(function(key) { 
                return key !== "Week" && key !== "Value" && key !== 'WeeklyActual' && key !== 'WeeklyPlan'
                 }));

              this.datas.forEach(function(d) {

                var dateObj = new Date(d.Week);
                var month = dateObj.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
                var day = dateObj.getUTCDate();
                var year = dateObj.getUTCFullYear();

                d.Week = new Date(month+'/'+day+'/'+year );

                // console.log( d.Week );

              });


              var cities = color.domain().map(function(name) {
                return {
                  name: name,
                  values: that.datas.map(function(d) {
                    return {date: d.Week, temperature: (+d[name]) };
                  })
                };
              });


              x.domain(d3.extent(this.datas, 
                function(d) { 
                    return d.Week;
                })
              );

              y.domain([
                d3.min(cities, function(c) { return d3.min(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); }),
                d3.max(cities, function(c) { return d3.max(c.values, function(v) { return v.temperature; }); })
              ]);

              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "x axis")
                  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                  .call(xAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .attr('class', 'text-xaxis')
                    .style("text-anchor", "end")
                    // .attr('dx', -40)
                    // .attr('dy', 60)
                    .attr("transform", function(d) {
                        return "rotate(-65)" 
                    });

              svg.append("g")
                  .attr("class", "y axis")
                  .call(yAxis)
                    .selectAll("text")
                    .attr('class', 'text-yaxis')
                    .attr('dx', -10)

                 var city = svg.selectAll(".city")
                      .data(cities)
                      .enter().append("g")
                      .attr('id', function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                        })
                      .attr("class", "city");

                var path = city.append("path")
                              .attr("class", "line")
                              .attr("d", function(d) { 
                                return line(d.values); 
                              })
                              .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

                var totalLength = [
                                    path[0][0].getTotalLength(),
                                    path[0][1].getTotalLength()
                                  ];

                 path
                      .attr("stroke-dasharray", totalLength + " " + totalLength)
                      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", totalLength)
                      .transition()
                      .duration(2000)
                      .ease("linear")
                      .attr("stroke-dashoffset", 0);

                var circles = city.selectAll("circle")
                        .data(function(d) {
                          return d.values
                        })
                        .enter()
                        .append("circle")
                        .attr("r", 3.5)
                        .attr("cx", function(d, i) {
                          return x(d.date)
                        })
                        .attr("cy", function(d) {
                          return y(d.temperature)
                        })
                        .style('cursor', 'pointer')
                        .attr("fill", "transparent")
                        .attr("stroke", "yellow")
                        .attr("stroke-width", 0);

                    circles.transition().duration(3000).attr("stroke-width", 2);


                    circles.on("mouseover", function(d, i) {

                        div.transition().duration(200).style("opacity", 0.9);

                        var data = d3.select(this.parentNode).select("path").data()[0];

                        var date = d.date;
                        var dateValues = date.getDate() +'/' + (date.getMonth() + 1) +'/' + date.getFullYear();

                        div.html( "<span>"+ data.name + ": </span><span>" + dateValues + '</span><span>' + d.temperature +'</span>')
                            .style("left", (d3.event.pageX) + "px")
                            .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 60) + "px");

                    })
                    .on("mouseout", function(d, i) {

                        div.transition().duration(500).style("opacity", 0);

                    })
```

Comment: the defined() function determines if the data point is drawn. I can't see where you're loading PlanPercentage into the data node, but you can just check for pp null in the defined() function

Comment: I agree. see the variable `var line = ` - i have added already. when i add this nothing is drawing for me. i am getting empty. as well getting no errors

Comment: i see it but I don't see where you're loading planpercentage into the nodes?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not able to get your point.Do you mean to say SVG part?

Comment: where in the code do you define y to be PlanPercentage? the values in your cities variable appear to only contain 'date' and 'temperature'

Answer (score 0):

from the idea of `softwarenewbie7331` I have modified the code like this: ( Y values )

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
.x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
.defined(function(d) { return d.temperature })
.y(function(d) { return y(d.temperature); });
```

this is working fine for me.